# Terraform Azure Function App Deployment - Representing settings

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to deploy an Azure Function App via Terraform

**I am getting the following errors when trying to represent the Function App settings:**

Error: azurerm_function_app.func-app-1: : invalid or unknown key: always_on

Error: azurerm_function_app.func-app-1: : invalid or unknown key: use_32_bit_worker_process

Error: azurerm_function_app.func-app-1: : invalid or unknown key: websockets_enabled

**Below is the code i am using:**

```
            resource "azurerm_function_app" "func-app-1" {
            name = "${var.func_app_1}"
            location = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.core-rg.location}"

            resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.core-rg.name}"

            app_service_plan_id = "${data.azurerm_app_service_plan.app-service-plan-1.id}"

            storage_connection_string = "${data.azurerm_storage_account.storage-account-1.primary_connection_string}"

            version                   = "~1"
            https_only                = "true"
            enabled                   = "true"
            always_on                 = "true"
            use_32_bit_worker_process = "false"
            websockets_enabled        = "true"
            client_affinity_enabled   = "false"

            app_settings {

            "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION" = "~1"

            "KeyVaultURI" = “”

            "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "6.5.0"

            }

            }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define the same under site_config. Please refer below code. You can add further

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "prod" {
  name                      = "${var.function_app_name}"
  location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.prod.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.prod.name}"
  app_service_plan_id       = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.prod.id}"
  storage_connection_string = "${azurerm_storage_account.prod.primary_connection_string}"
  version                   = "~2"
  app_settings = {
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY              = "${azurerm_application_insights.prod.instrumentation_key}"
    FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION                 = "~2"
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME                    = "dotnet"
    WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING    = "${azurerm_storage_account.prod.primary_connection_string}"
    WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE                        = "${var.storage_account_name}"
  }
  site_config {
    always_on   = "true"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to define app settings in variables.tf

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "func-app-1" {
            name = "${var.func_app_1}"
            location = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.core-rg.location}"

            resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.core-rg.name}"

            app_service_plan_id = "${data.azurerm_app_service_plan.app-service-plan-1.id}"

            storage_connection_string = "${data.azurerm_storage_account.storage-account-1.primary_connection_string}"

            version                   = "~1"
            https_only                = "true"
            enabled                   = "true"
            always_on                 = "true"
            use_32_bit_worker_process = "false"
            websockets_enabled        = "true"
            client_affinity_enabled   = "false"
            app_settings              = "${var.app_settings}"
}
```

In variables.tf

```
variable "app_settings" {
    description = "A key-value pair of App Settings"
    default     = {
        "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION" = "~1",
        "KeyVaultURI" = “”,
        "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "6.5.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add those values that are erroring  in a site_config block as per the docs here : https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/app_service.html

Comment: Actually this link but the answer is the same: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/function_app.html